# Check to call sql script from different page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages - the first page has two buttons and clicking on either of them will run different SQL queries and transfer them to the second page in a GridView.  Upon page load, I have two different IF statements: the first one will run the first query and second will run the second query.  My question is - how would I do the check to see if that button was clicked?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
public partial class Page2: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (page1 button1 is clicked) //this is what I need help with
        {
            //run sql...
        }
        else if (page1 button2 is clicked) //this will be similar to the first
        {
            //run sql...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: See the following post. I think you are trying to do the same thing:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853028/how-to-detect-which-button-was-clicked-in-code-behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a session state to store which button was clicked. So in the button event, just have

```
protected void button1_OnClikc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    session["WhichButtonWasClicked"] = "Button1";
}
```

On the Page load of the next page you can read that session value.

```
If (Session["WhichButtonWasClicked"] == "Button1")
{
 // Button 1 is clicked
}
else
{
//Button 2
}
```

Another option is to pass the button click information as a URL parameter. You could also store the information in a cookie, store it in a DB and retrieve it later. Lots of options!

Comment: Thanks for the options, I will be trying these out.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SESSIONS, when your button is pressed, you should assign a value to a Session variable, for example:

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Session["buttonPressed"] = "button1";
    // your query and transfer code here
}

protected void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Session["buttonPressed"] = "button2";
    // your query and transfer code here
}
```

The session variable will keep the value through the pages, so then use a switch if you want

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (Session["buttonPressed"].ToString())
    {
        case "button1":
        //Your code if the button1 was pressed
        break;
        case "button2":
        //Your code if the button2 was pressed    
        break;
        default: 
        //Your code if you have a default action/code
        break;
    }
}
```